# Rest Assured: Extracting value from JSON Array

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am trying to extract values from JSON array with rest assured using jsonPath.

Example JSON Response:

```
{
    "notices": [],
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "UNAUTHORIZED"
        }
    ]
}
```

Current test is below:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "somePayLoadProvider", dataProviderClass = MyPayLoadProvider.class)
public void myTestMethod(SomePayload myPayload) {
    Response r = given().
            spec(myRequestSpecification).
            contentType(ContentType.JSON).
            body(myPayload).
            post("/my-api-path");

    List<String> e = r.getBody().jsonPath().getList("errors.code");
    assertEquals(e, hasItem(MyErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED.error()));
}
```

however, i keep getting [] around my error code. I would just like the value.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected 
[a collection containing "UNAUTHORIZED"] but found [[UNAUTHORIZED]]

Expected :a collection containing "UNAUTHORIZED"
Actual   :[UNAUTHORIZED]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was just me not using `assert()` methods correctly.

Changed

`assertEquals(e, hasItem(MyErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED.error()));`

to

`assertTrue(e.contains(MyErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED.error()));`

The parsing of the json was done correctly to an `ArrayList<String>`

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you could specify the array index of 'errors' to remove the square brackets. ie:

```
    List<String> e = r.getBody().jsonPath().getList("errors[0].code");
```

then you can return to using 'equals' rather than 'contains'

Answer (score 1):

With rest-assured, you could also do chained assertions inline with the REST call like so:

```
given()
  .spec(myRequestSpecification)
  .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
  .body(myPayload)
  .post("/my-api-path") //this returns Response
  .then()               //but this returns ValidatableResponse; important difference
  .statusCode(200)
  .body("notices", hasSize(0)) // any applicable hamcrest matcher can be used
  .body("errors", hasSize(1))
  .body("errors", contains(MyErrorType.UNAUTHORIZED.error()));
```